# How can I use Pandas DataFrame and sent to Discord

Tags: python, pandas, discord, discord.py, gspread

I'm currently developing a Discord Bot that get message(User ID) strings from a Google spreadsheet and returns the corresponding data. But I think the way I am using the DataFrame is not correct, is there any other better way.

````
import aiohttp
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials as SAC
import gspread
import pandas as pd

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
Json = 'xxx.json'
Connect = SAC.from_json_keyfile_name(Json, scope)
GoogleSheets = gspread.authorize(Connect)
sheet = GoogleSheets.open_by_key('key')
Sheets = sheet.sheet1   
df = pd.DataFrame(Sheets.get_all_records())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    bot.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------------')
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    bot.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    
@bot.command()
async def LList(message, a: str):     

    MIT = await df[df['Discord ID'] == message]['ticket\n(total)'][0]
    await message.send("```\n{}\n You have {} ticket```".format(a, str(MIT)))
       
bot.run('key')
````

and I got Error here, I don't think there is a way for me to use the local package, but I don't know if there is any other way to do the same thing.

```
Ignoring exception in command list:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\user\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1625, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1632, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\user\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-42-1c34e43fc9a7>", line 33, in LList
    MIT = await df[df['Discord ID'] == message]['ticket\n(total)'][0]
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\user\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 824, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\user\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 932, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\user\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\user\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\user\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\user\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 0
```

Thanks in advance for your Answers.

Answer (score 0):

`MIT = await df[df['Discord ID'] == message]['ticket\n(total)'][0]`
I'm not sure why you would need `await` here try removing it even though I'm unsure that would resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

`message` is a [commands.Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#context) object, so you are probably wanting `message.author.id` or something. I think nicofrlo is probably right about not needing `await` there also.

The easiest way to debug this would probably be to use the python terminal to get the desired df and play around with `df[df['Discord ID'] == message.author.id]['ticket\n(total)'][0]` in the terminal so that you can see what's going on before trying to pass it around to discord.